# How to use Prestashop's controllers in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, prestashop

I'm developing an Intranet in Laravel and I need to use Controllers from Prestashop 1.7 due to get the token url from backOffice urls, for exemple:
https://www.test.com/test/index.php?controller=AdminOrders&vieworder=&id_order=00000&token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
The project is in prestashop folder.
How can I use these controllers in my laravel project?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$_POST['id_shop'] = 1;// Put your shop id
include($PrestaShopPath . '/config/config.inc.php');
include($PrestaShopPath . '/init.php');
$context->employee = new Employee(1);// your employee id
//dump($context);
$token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminOrders');
echo $token;
// OR
$token = Tools::getAdminToken('AdminOrders'. 
    (int)Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminOrders'). 
    1); // your employee id
echo $token;
```

Comment: It doesn't works. Laravel thrown me a exception: Cannot redeclare Matrix\adjoint().

Comment: @michu You can not mix PrestasShop with Laravel. put this file in your prestashop root and call it to get your token. It is a simple sample. you can use variable instead of "AdminOrders" and return token as a response

Comment: It works, but the main problem stills, when I enter to the prestashop backOffice with addres client (for exemple) and the generate token, prestashop tells me that the token is invalidad.

Comment: The token is different for each employee. At first, you must logging in by one employee through the codes.  then you can get token.

Comment: I use this code, but I think thats not the correct way                                     `<?php`

`include('config/config.inc.php');`
`include('init.php');`

`$employee_session = $_GET['employee'];`
`$employee_session = json_decode($employee_session);`

`$context = Context::getContext();`
`$context->employee = new Employee($employee_session['id_employee'], 0);`

`$token = Tools::getToken(false);`
`echo $token;`

`?> `

Comment: Updated: you just need "id_employee" to retrieve token. If not, you have to use PrestaShop webservice but you need new module to handle your needs.

Comment: How can I login by php to the backOffice ? I'm loocking for information but i didn't cacht something

Comment: Updated: use this way to login

Comment: but can I logging without passw?

Comment: @michu I do not know your ultimate goal, but anyway with this code you can get the desired  AdminController 's token